# What is minimum possible size of Hikari connection pool?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am working on developing a spring-boot based microservice of which dozens of application instances will run concurrently. I am planning to use HikariCP as our database connection pooling tool to connect with MySQL databases. However, when I try to create connection pools varying in size from 0-10, I am able to create connection pools that vary in size from 1-10 but never reach the sweet spot of 0 during idle time.

My configuration,

```
HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();

hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);
hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(60000);

hikariConfig.setPoolName(poolName);
hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
hikariConfig.setUsername(userName);
hikariConfig.setPassword(password);
hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(databaseDriverClass);

return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
```

I'd like to understand if HikariCP has a hard limit where it can never reach a size of less than 1 idle connection?

Comment: What's wrong with a minimum size of 1? If the size is zero, then the first query coming in would take some time to run. Also, I would think that the pool needs 1 connection to check for a heart beat on the database engine; it's probably sending dummy queries silently and periodically to check this.

Comment: A minimum size of 1 is a huge problem when you have 50 instances of the same application. And if the connections are sitting idle, at any given time you might have upto 50 connections sitting idle and useless. Our databases are shared such that we have 1 schema per customer. For each schema we have a separate user. Due to this we have to spin up a separate connection pool per schema

Comment: In this case I would think that using an orchestrator like Kubernetes or OpenShift can be a better option. The orchestator won't have 50 idle instances running all the time. Instead it would have only a couple of them running in low traffic hours and it would scale up automatically as needed during medium or high load hours.

Comment: As much as I agree with what you just said, making this change to the infrastructure would be time-consuming and at this moment we are looking for a possible solution from within. 

We'd ideally want connection pools to grow down to zero in idle times and grow back up upon the need of the hour

Comment: And, by the way, I have a SpringBoot app running with 10 max instances in OpenShift. Runs like a breeze and scales up and down by itself.

Comment: As I said earlier, it is a wonderful eventual solution but maybe not something we could achieve instantaneously

Comment: `allowPoolSuspension=true` property could be tried over JMX to see if it closes all connections. Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: So, no answer to this then, or does no-one know if a pool size can be 0. I am writing a CLI app and want the initial size to 0.

Comment: Actually, the above does work. My initial observation was incorrect. After a the minimum idle time has passed the connections start terminating.